# I booted UBUNTU to a USB flashdrive. How can I run it now?

Tags: command-line

Please help, I did the complete step by step guide, got UBUNTU onto my flash drive but I can't seem to open it. How do I do this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The Ubuntu ISO (image file) needs to be expanded & written to the thumb-drive.  Myself I use `dd` to write it to my thumb-drives; but you didn't tell provide us with much hence icebunny08's question.  The instructions I assume you followed were https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 where on the thumb-drive should 'boot' (which is machine & security specific but may involve just putting it in your machine & turning the machine on, may require keys to boot it).  You need to 'boot' it to use it, rather than 'open' it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done everything perfectly while making bootable drive  , then you will see some different icon of USB.  If that is correct then you should plug in your USB. Then go to your BIOS settings. There you may have to press esc , f2 ,f10 or f12 (fully depends upon your pc). These will mostly appear below the boot menu . If you have pressed correctly then you will see blue screen.  If not then reboot oncemore and try. After going into that bios menu, you should select your USB by arrows and enter key. Then you will boot up there you press install ubuntu or you can try ubuntu and then decide whether or not use ubuntu and then install with icon in desktop. There you first select language, keyboard format etc. Then if you want to dualboot then give install ubuntu along with windows or you can replace windows if you want. Then it will install (note: you should allocate drive with recommended space for ubuntu as for windows ).
Then remove USB and you should see a grub menu insterd of regular windows boot . There you can select ubuntu and use.